# Google Play Instant Development SDK Update Fails

Tags: android-studio, google-play, android-studio-3.2

Android Studio 3.2 RC3 keeps asking me to update the Google Play Instant Development SDK (from 1.3.0 to 1.4.0), but it always fails the update with this message:

> Failed packages:
>   - Google Play Instant Development SDK (extras;google;instantapps)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to get this working by:

1. Closing my project (File -> Close Project)
2. Open *SDK Manager* from the gear at the bottom of the window
3. Click *Updates* on the left
4. I had to do this twice and it worked the second time.

If that won't work you can try File -> Invalidate Cache/restart -> Invalidate Restart. Android Studio will close and restart and then updates should install properly.

Answer (score 27):

- **Close Android Studio completely**

`File -> Close.`

- **Delete `instantapps` Folder form your sdk**:

`C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\instantapps`

- **update again.**

read more http://syscurity.blogspot.com/2018/09/failed-packages-google-play-instant.html

Comment: By default the folder instantapps is in AppData\..., but to be exact: It´s in <AndroidSDKInstallFolder>\extras\google, which can be anywhere.

Comment: Oops, edit expired:
But the actual reason for this post is my annoyance that this syscurity site uses 50% processor on my 45W Skylake, making me wonder what B* it does in the background! (The max I saw in normal ops is under 30%!)

Comment: This solution is actually included in the comments when the error occurs.  This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks and this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

After delete, you reinstall here "Instant"

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. find the SDK folder instalation,
2. go to extra-google-instantaps, delete that
   folder instantaps
3. and after that update again with sdk manager, that
   old version is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Solved this (in a similar way to previous, with one exception) by

1: Closing Android Studio File -> Close

2: deleting .installer and tools folders in C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\instantapps

3: Launching SDK Manager from Configure dropdown beside gear icon

Note: I tried deleting the entire instantapps folder but when I did this I did not get presented with the option to
install Instant Development SDK.

Comment: Nailed it. I followed these steps and a new button popped up near the gear icon reporting the update available and now this issue is solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. Close Android Studio
2. Go to the SDK installed folder
   `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`
   or maybe you installed in another drive
3. Then go to `extras\google\instantapps` and delete this instant apps folder.
4. Now open Android Studio
5. Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> Check the box before
   *"Google Play Instant Development 
   SDK"*
6. Click Apply and ok
7. Enjoy your problem free life.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of Android Studio is 3.2, you can go to C:\Users\xxx and delete the version folder other than <.AndroidStudio3.2>. I did this and it succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Just needs Administrator privilege to install. Try run Android studio as administrator.