# Install Google Play Instant Development SDK (revision: 1.5.0) failed

Tags: android-studio

How can I fix this?

```
Packages to install:<br>
- Google Play Instant Development SDK (extras;google;instantapps)

Preparing "Install Google Play Instant Development SDK (revision: 1.5.0)".
<br>Found existing prepared package.

<br>"Install Google Play Instant Development SDK (revision: 1.5.0)" ready.
<br>"Install Google Play Instant Development SDK (revision: 1.5.0)" complete.
<br>"Install Google Play Instant Development SDK (revision: 1.5.0)" failed.
<br>Failed to complete operation using com.android.tools.idea.sdk.install.patch.FullInstaller, retrying with com.android.repository.impl.installer.BasicInstaller
<br>Preparing "Install Google Play Instant Development SDK (revision: 1.5.0)".
<br>Found existing prepared package.
<br>"Install Google Play Instant Development SDK (revision: 1.5.0)" ready.
<br>Installing Google Play Instant Development SDK in C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\instantapps
<br>An error occurred during installation: Failed to move away or delete existing target file: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\instantapps
<br>Move it away manually and try again..
<br>"Install Google Play Instant Development SDK (revision: 1.5.0)" complete.
<br>"Install Google Play Instant Development SDK (revision: 1.5.0)" failed.
<br>Failed packages:
- Google Play Instant Development SDK (extras;google;instantapps)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play Instant Development SDK Update Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52322030/google-play-instant-development-sdk-update-fails)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play Instant Development SDK Update Fails](//stackoverflow.com/questions/52322030/google-play-instant-development-sdk-update-fails)

Comment: i have done like "http://syscurity.blogspot.com/2018/09/failed-packages-google-play-instant.html", but i face some problem in my other projects

Comment: @MohammadSultanAlNahiyan did you come to a solution?

Answer (score 14):

As explained [here](http://syscurity.blogspot.com/), already annotated under your question, deleting the `\instantapps` folder in `C:\[Users]\[UserName]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\instantapps` could be the solution.

Answer (score 3):

delete instantapps folder in your Android Sdk path `...\extras\google\instantapps`